# How to analyze PermGen space?

Tags: java, jvm, permgen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to analyze PermGen contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842982/how-to-analyze-permgen-contents)

I want to know what is occupying the PermGen space - string intern() or classes? Is there any tool which will help with this analysis?

Comment: Those links should answer your first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262328/how-is-the-java-memory-pool-divided/1262474#1262474 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095748/method-area-and-permgen.

Comment: I don't see how those links help the OP at all.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842982/how-to-analyze-permgen-contents

Comment: @Perception They give some information about what goes to PermGen but your link is admittedly better.

Comment: @assylias - The OP does appear to know what PermGen is for, hence my comment. In any case, the question looks like a duplicate.

Comment: I tried the utility to print a running JVM's string literal pool(https://github.com/puneetlakhina/javautils/blob/master/com/blogspot/sahyog/PrintStringTable.java)...  But i'm getting below error... Attaching to process ID 8980, please wait...
Error attaching to process: Timed out while attempting to connect to debug server (please start SwDbgSrv.exe)..

Comment: Any idea.. how to start SwDbgSrv.exe in windows 7

Comment: @user1325695 You should create a new question with that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Memory Analysis

1. Use  `jvisualvm.exe`  present in bin directory of JDK
2. Using jvisualvm  take the Thread/Heap dump depending on the `process id` of the  Application 
   you need to profile.
3. [Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) an eclipse plugin. where you can import the heap dump from jvisualvm and analyze for possible leaks.

Comment: Don't you mean heap dump instead of thread dump?

Comment: @tom If you want to do a CPU profiling then take thread dump . if you want to do a memory Analysis take a heap dump ..

Comment: He is talking about memory and your response states thread dump.

Comment: @tom thanks i missed it added

Comment: @Downvoter please provide the reason , It helps me to correct myself if i have gone wrong or answer is wrong. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use monitoring tools that are in the bin folder of your jdk, as "jvisualvm" or "jconsole"

Answer (score 0):

I use [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/) to analyse what is in the heap-space.  It is not free but it is a really big help when analysing memory issues and/or performance issues.  (They have an evaluation version)