# Orika and usage of PermGen Space

Tags: out-of-memory, permgen, orika

Since some days we're using Orika for Class Mapping in our production environment. Now it seems that we have a problem with the PermGen Space. We need more then twice as much PermGen Space then before and had some OutOfMemoryError's. 
Is it possible that Orika is producing this memory consumption in the PermGen? Respectively what is the best way to improve this situation?

I read something about the VM-flag -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled, which forces the PermGen to collect the garbage. Can this help?

regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Never experienced such issues (even on large projects),

Some unit test included in Orika that verify some key performance issues:
[You can find them here](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/tree/master/tests/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/test/perf)

To be sure consider to use a [profiler/memory analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753176/how-to-analyze-permgen-space).